# Matrix Transpose SOS

Tags: matrices, transpose

I am taking my first Linear Algebra Class in college and it is one of the hardest math classes I have ever taken. It is my introduction to proofs and the semester just started. I am very lost in the class and here is an example of one problem I can't seem to understand.

I have to prove that $\mathrm{Col}_i (A') = \mathrm{Row}_i (A)'$ and that $\mathrm{Col}_j (A') = \mathrm{Row}_j (A)'$. In the problem it says "the transpose of $A$ is the matrix $A' = (b_{ij})$ where $b_{ij} = a_{ji}$".

It would be great to have an abstract explanation and an applied explanation, which I think will help me understand it much better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: I made some edits, how's that?

Comment: Try to work with little examples, for instance $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$$ Do you see why $Col_{1}(A')=Row_{1}(A)'$ ? Replace $A$ by $$B=\begin{bmatrix}
 a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
 a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \end{bmatrix}$$ Do you see why $Col_{1}(B')=Row_{1}(B)'$ ?

Comment: Oh okay. I can work with that!

Comment: So, in my proof should I start by saying, "Let A=...."

Comment: My previous comment was only to tell you how to get the intuition and how you can see what happens. For writing your proof, you could start by something like : Let $M$ a $n \times m$ matrix
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
 a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots & a_{1m}\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
 a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \dots & a_{nm}\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I think I see where I can go from here.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments (I post this as an answer, since it seems that the problem was solved):

Try to work with little examples, for instance $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$$ Do you see why $\mathrm{Col}_{1}(A')=\mathrm{Row}_{1}(A)'$ ? Replace $A$ by $$B=\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \end{bmatrix}$$ Do you see why $\mathrm{Col}_{1}(B')=\mathrm{Row}_{1}(B)'$ ?

This is just a way to understand how to get the intuition and how you can see what happens.

For writing your proof, you could start by something like : Let $M$ a $n \times m$ matrix $$M=\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots & a_{1m}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\ a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \dots & a_{nm}\\ \end{bmatrix}$$ [and so on].